# Jess and FuzzyJ assistance

Tags: fuzzy, jess

I'm trying to learn Jess and FuzzyJ but am having problems getting a simple program to run. I have looked at it for hours and am no quite sure why it doesn't run. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Fuzzy Variables
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defglobal ?*income* = 
    (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "income" 0.0 230000.00 "dollars"))
(defglobal ?*stability* =
    (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "stability" 0.0 1.0 "index"))
(defglobal ?*liquidity* =
    (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "liquidity" 0.0 1.0 "index"))



(defrule initial-terms
    (declare (salience 100))
=>
(import nrc.fuzzy.*)
(load-package nrc.fuzzy.jess.FuzzyFunctions)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Primary Terms
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


(?*income* addTerm "low" (new ZFuzzySet 30000.00 80000.00))
(?*income* addTerm "medium" (new PIFuzzySet 100000.00 60000.00))
(?*income* addTerm "high" (new SFuzzySet 80000.00 190000.00))

(?*stability* addTerm "low" (new ZFuzzySet .3 .5))
(?*stability* addTerm "medium" (new PIFuzzySet .6 .4))
(?*stability* addTerm "high" (new SFuzzySet .7 .9))

(?*liquidity* addTerm "low" (new ZFuzzySet .3 .5))
(?*liquidity* addTerm "medium" (new PIFuzzySet .6 .4))
(?*liquidity* addTerm "high" (new SFuzzySet .7 . 9))
)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Fuzzy Rules
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defrule rule-1 "low income => liquidity very low"
    (theIncome ?x &: (fuzzy-match ?x "low"))
=>

    (assert(theLiquidity (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyValue ?*liquidity* "very low")))

(defrule rule-2 "high income & high stability => very high liquidity"
    (theIncome ?x &: (fuzzy-match ?x "high"))
    (theStability ?y (fuzzy-match ?y "high"))
=>
    (assert(theLiquidity (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyValue ?*liquidity* "very high"))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Defuzzification
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defrule defuzzification-and-display-liquidity
    (declare (salience -1))
    ?f <- (theLiquidity ?z)
=>
    (printout t (str-cat "Liquidity: " (?z momentDefuzzify)))
    retract( ?f)
    (halt))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Start up Rule/Fuzzify
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defrule assert-income-and-stability "initialization"
=>
    (printout t "Enter the income(ex. 52000): ")
    (bind ?income-value (float (readline t)))

    (printout t "Enter the stability index(ex. 0.64): ")
    (bind ?stability-value (float(readline t)))


    (assert(theIncome
        (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyValue ?*income*
        (new nrc.fuzzy.TriangleFuzzySet
        (- ?income-value 3000.0)
        ?income-value
        (+ ?income-value 3000.0)))))

    (assert(theStability
        (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyValue ?*stability*
        (new nrc.fuzzy.TriangleFuzzySet
        (- ?stability-value 3000.0)
        ?stability-value
        (+ ?stability-value 3000.0))))))

(reset)
(run)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many small syntax errors in this program; in general the Jess interpreter does a good job of pointing them out. First of all, in each of your comment blocks, you've got  the actual text of the comment... not commented. So add a semicolon to the beginning of the lines like "Fuzzy Variables", for instance.

Second, on the line

```
(?*liquidity* addTerm "high" (new SFuzzySet .7 . 9))
```

there ought to be no space after that last decimal point.

Third, the rules `rule-1` and `rule-2` don't have enough close-parentheses at the end. Any decent programmer's editor able to format Lisp code should be able to help you fix that.

Fourth, on the line

```
(theStability ?y (fuzzy-match ?y "high"))
```

you're missing the "&:" before the predicate function -- see the previous line.

Finally, I think, the line

```
retract( ?f)
```

is malformed -- should be `(retract ?f)` .